# Every other celery task fails; it seems to be "unregistered"

Tags: python, queue, celery

I'm using `celery` to run a task called `'filter'`.

I'm having a weird error whereby **every other** task call seems to result in a `celery.exceptions.NotRegistered` exception.

By *every other call*, I mean:

- I call it once, it works
- I call it again, it fails (with the error below)
- I call it for the third time, it works again.
- I call it for a fourth time, it fails (same error) message

I'm calling it using `send_task` like this, storing the `task_id` so I can pool it later.

```
async_result1 = celery_app.send_task("filter", kwargs=data.dict())

output = {"task_id": async_result1.task_id}
```

**Then** I poll the app every few seconds to get the status of the task like this:

```
result=AsyncResult(task_id)

(if status is not success, keep polling until it's successful)
```

The weird thing is that the code works once but when I call again it fails.

I've ssh'ed into the worker container and when I run `celery result` passing a failed task Id like this `celery -A app.name result -t filter  880df2ee-0a25-455f-93fb-50af3d5980e5`, this is the output I get (the last line shows the error I mentioned above)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
    _main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 495, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 305, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 487, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 419, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 309, in run_from_argv
    sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 393, in handle_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 253, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/bin/result.py", line 41, in run
    value = task_result.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 228, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 195, in wait_for_pending
    return result.maybe_throw(callback=callback, propagate=propagate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 333, in maybe_throw
    self.throw(value, self._to_remote_traceback(tb))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 326, in throw
    self.on_ready.throw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 244, in throw
    reraise(type(exc), exc, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 195, in reraise
    raise value
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'filter'
```

**Any idea of what could be happening here? I feel like there's something I'm missing, maybe I need to flush/restart the queue somehow?**

- I'm using `docker-compose` and this is how the worker container is being started:

  `celery worker -A app.name -P threads --loglevel=DEBUG`
- One curiosity here: I started off passing `--queues` parameter to the `celery worker **no call whatsoever worked**. When I removed the` --queues` parameter, it started behaving like it is now. Every other call fails.
- When I run `celery inspect` to view the worker state, I notice that only the tasks that end up successful are added to the queue

  ```
  root@604dce1e1dda:/workers# celery -A app.name inspect active
  -> celery@76089a886b04: OK
    - empty -
  -> celery@604dce1e1dda: OK
    * {'id': '4d35d0bf-e3b4-4a6b-9a2e-4b23e12c98b1', 'name': 'filter', 'args': [], 'kwargs': {'foo': 'bar'}, 'type': 'filter', 'hostname': 'celery@604dce1e1dda', 'time_start': 1671406221.0351112, 'acknowledged': True, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': False}, 'worker_pid': 1}
  ```
- The task is properly registered (but only the one that ends in `1dda`, it seems)

  ```
  root@604dce1e1dda:/workers# celery -A app.name inspect registered
  -> celery@76089a886b04: OK
     * model
  -> celery@604dce1e1dda: OK
     * filter
  ```

PS. : I'm running `celery 4.4.0 (cliffs)` on `python 3.7.16`